# How AWS Lambda receives adaptive card input in Teams

Tags: amazon-web-services, botframework, microsoft-teams

We want to post an adaptive card (with choices) message in Teams and receive the results of the choices input via AWS Lambda.

What is the usual way of implementing this?

Also, we are considering a method that does not use the Bot Framework if possible, but is it difficult to implement this in a simple way by specifying the URL of the endpoint on the AWS side in the variables of the adaptive card (e.g. action.submit)?

We implemented an adaptive card for sending messages to the teams, but we had a problem with where to specify the endpoint when replying to the lambda.

Comment: This issue is being addressed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1419330/teams-aws-lambda. Please check above thread for further updates.